# \ifcase suddenly complaning "Extra \or"

Tags: macros

For some strange reason, I have an `\ifcase` which has started to complain "Extra \or" but since `\ifcase` can have many `\or`s, how can it have an "extra" one?

It's part of a large package, the relevant bit, which has worked for years, is below. It doesn't like the second `\or` any more:

```
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:family}{#1}{#3}{#5}{}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family}{#1}{#3}{}{}}%
  \or
     \ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#4}{#5}{}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#4}{}{}}%
  \or
     \ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#3}{#5}{}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}{#1}{#3}{}{}}%
  \fi
```

If I change the second `\or` to an `\else`, I get an "Extra \else" error.

Comment: Please post the relevant document

Comment: `\or` after `\else` ?

Comment: TeX thinks it's seen an `\else`  or you have a stray `\or`.

Comment: a lonely \or gives this message.

Comment: perhaps the bibmacro is faulty and inserts a \fi.

Comment: Yes, it must be something there, you're right.

Comment: Hmm, but they are standard biblatex macros and if they were broken, I'd expect to see a lot of other problems ...

Comment: really the macro is called `\ifuseprefix` but isn't a TeX `\if` ? that's unfortunate.  put \tracingall just before that and post the log, that should show easily enough where the error is.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/seizaugt9fjcglp/log.txt?dl=0

Comment: `\ifuseprefix` is just `\def\ifuseprefix{\iftoggle{blx@useprefix}}`.

Comment: Looking at the log, `\ifdefvoid` is passed an empty argument, so `\ifdefined #1\ifx #1\relax` compares `\ifx` with `\relax` and `\ifx` disappears, so the `\fi` which is meant to match it is instead matched to the enclosing `\ifcase`. The following `\or` is in an improper place.

Comment: As @egreg says, that's the issue: tracing back, the empty argument comes from `\usebibmacro {name:given-family}{\namepartfamily }{\namepartgiveni }{\namepartprefix }{}` which needs to have something in that last part (as defined in your use case: doesn't look like the standard version to me!).

Comment: That's it, thanks. This way of avoiding name parts won't work any more in this style. Putting `\relax` instead of nothing at all fixes it ... @egreg, if you turn the comment to an answer, I'll accept it - you just pipped Joseph to the post ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
\ifdefvoid #1->\ifundef {#1} {\@firstoftwo } {\ifdefmacro {#1} {\ifdefparam {#1} {\@secondoftwo } {\etb@ifdefempty {#1}}} {\@secondoftwo }}
#1<-

\ifundef #1->\ifdefined #1\ifx #1\relax \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \@firstoftwo \else \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \@secondoftwo \fi \else \expandafter \@firstoftwo \fi 
#1<-
{\ifdefined: (level 3) entered on line 13}
{true}
{\relax}
{\expandafter}
{\expandafter}
{\else: \ifdefined (level 3) entered on line 13}
{\fi: \ifdefined (level 3) entered on line 13}
{\expandafter}
{\else: \ifcase (level 2) entered on line 13}
{\fi: \ifcase (level 2) entered on line 13}
```

When `\ifdefvoid` is called, it is passed an empty argument, so the next instruction becomes

```
\ifdefined \ifx\relax \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \@firstoftwo \else \expandafter \expandafter \expandafter \@secondoftwo \fi \else \expandafter \@firstoftwo \fi
```

and `\ifdefined` looks at `\ifx`, which *is* defined, but it's also removed from the input stream, so the `\fi` that was meant to match it matches instead the outer `\ifcase`, as seen in

```
{\else: \ifcase (level 2) entered on line 13}
{\fi: \ifcase (level 2) entered on line 13}
```

The next `\or` becomes misplaced.